# SQL sorting by 0

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Im having some difficulties trying to order my list of a resultset. Im trying to create pagination. I have a table called Track. I use the following sql to retrieve a list of identies used by my pagination:

```
SELECT trackid FROM track ORDER BY filelength limit 10
```

Wich results in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then after that i execute the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM track ORDER BY filelength ASC LIMIT 10
```

and i receive the following:

```
250   Track 250    0
251   Track 251    0   
252   Track 252    0   
253   Track 253    0   
254   Track 254    0   
255   Track 255    0   
256   Track 256    0   
257   Track 257    0   
258   Track 258    0   
259   Track 259    0
```

In the second resultset i see that the resultset gives different tracks, i would expect the same id's from first resultset, but it seems to start at 250. Why is this happening?

I have about 20000 rows in this table, and all of the column filelength columns are 0.

Im running a Mysql server 5.1.30 - community version

Comment: What's the difference between `track` and `playitem`?

Comment: @Terraego....I am unclear as to your issue.  Would you want the second resultset to start at 261?

Comment: I trust that a query with `LIMIT 10` does not return 11 rows like in your second example.

Comment: I modified my question, it was late at the time. Track and Playitem are the same tables, i modified the original question. Limit 10 does indeed return 10 rows :)/

I Want my second resultset to start at 1. I dont see why i get different rows when selecting different columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it yourself:

> and all of the column filelength columns are 0.

So `ORDER BY filelength` is just noise, and **arbitrary** rows will be returned. The database engine will pick *any* rows in an implementation specific way, because all of them equally qualify and no particular order is specified.

There is **no such thing as a "natural order"** in a table of a relational database. You seem to be assuming that.

Use meaningful columns in your `ORDER BY` to select rows in a defined sequence. Like:

```
SELECT trackid FROM track ORDER BY trackid LIMIT 10;
```

---

To achieve this:

> I basicly want a resultset that only contains the id's of the second
>   query (optionally without the limit)

Try:

```
SELECT trackid
FROM   track
WHERE  trackid BETWEEN 250 AND 259
ORDER  BY trackid;
```

Comment: I undestand what your trying to say, but i dont quite follow. I would expect the rows to start at 1-10. I basicly want a resultset that only contains the id's of the second query (optionally without the limit)

Comment: Thanks a lot, too bad the ordering is arbitrary. Thanks for the query.

Comment: @Terraego no it is not a bad thing, you are using this feature the wrong way, order clause should always be deterministic :)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli i guess i am, im using the first query to generate a list of id's so i can create a cache. then with the second query, i try to load the list and store a part in that cache. I guess il have to think of something else

Answer (score 0):

You're pulling from two different tables. `playitem` is not `track`:

```
SELECT trackid FROM playitem ORDER BY filelength limit 10
SELECT * FROM track ORDER BY filelength ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Very sharp indeed, i renamed the table to track for clarity, i editted the original question

Answer (score -1):

Well if you are trying to use this for pagination. In SQL the LIMIT clause can take two arguments. With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

For example, the first one would be:

```
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The next one would be:

```
LIMIT 10, 10
```

The next one would be:

```
LIMIT 20, 10
```

And so on...

Comment: Im not asking anything about the limit keyword, i understand how this works. But thank you for your time anyway :)